# 'Recurse into subdirectories' and 'Apply to files only' checkboxes missing for files in FileZilla

Tags: linux, ftp, filezilla

I cannot install any plugin on my website (states cannot create directory), which had crashed after upgrading to a new woocommerce 5.1.1 version. After having spent days and nights working on the issue I have realised that on FTP client I need to enable recurse into subdirectories option checkbox for files only under the `Public_html`. However the checkbox is missing, all I have under file permissions is the option to add a numeric value of 644 and nothing else. The boxes for recurse, etc which are meant to be below are missing. Could you please advise as to how I can have these boxes displayed in case they are hidden on FileZilla?

Answer (score 0):

The options are there, if you have selected any folder only.

When you select only files, the options do not make sense, so they are hidden.